# Posting a question only to answer it yourself

Tags: discussion

Some users seem to post questions only to answer it a few minutes later. I'm not sure why they're doing this and in my opinion they questions themselves aren't of that high quality.

For example: [Programmatically 301 Redirect](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9848/programmatically-301-redirect). The question is something you can easily find with a Google search. So is this something we should ignore or should we delete / flag these kinds of threads.

In my opinion Magento SE shouldn't be someones place to store code snippets, there are enough online services already.

Comment: Related question on the network meta site: [What is this “answer your own question” jazz?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz)

Answer (score 5):

I disagree with Marius on this, and agree with xyphoid's answer.

Whether a question is trivial or not, it shouldn't be an issue. When it's on topic and magento related, it should be allowed.

Like xyphoid said:

> one person's trivial question is something someone else wasted an afternoon figuring out

The ability to find an answer with a Google search should be meaningless when the result isn't on http://magento.stackexchange.com (i.e. not a duplicate). The idea is having a large enough FAQ to cover most of possible Magento questions and issues that people have.

For example, I definitely disagree that the question linked in this question is trivial.
There are lots of way to do a redirect. So having a question mentioning what's the correct way to do it with the community agreeing/disagreeing (i.e. upvoting/downvoting) on how it's done, is really important.

Keep in mind, not everyone is a Magento or Zend or PHP expert. Someone could be coming from a `.NET` background for example.

Comment: Good point, thanks for sharing your view on the way Mage SE should work in relation to Googling and from that perspective I agree with you. My only concern is this becoming someones snippet bin. I guess it's a matter of opinion :)

Answer (score 4):

If the question isn't a duplicate or anything I think this should be totally fine - one person's trivial question is something someone else wasted an afternoon figuring out.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0):

This has been a question of mine for a while, and I'm glad to see that it seems to be generally okay to do so. Many of the things I'm searching for seem to be obscure or partially answered on a blog from 4 years ago and would benefit from an updated answer here.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see something wrong in posting answers to your own questions. But I agree with you on this. If the quality is poor or it's something (let's say) trivial, someone should take some actions. I say that we should just flag these questions and let the moderators decide on their quality.

Comment: Agreed, some awesome coding snippet that everyone should know about would actually be great but how to do a 301 redirect is a bit to trivial. Anyway, I flagged it. thanks for the answer :)